# angular-moment-meteor Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm using **angular-moment-meteor** and when I use `am-time-ago`directive, like below, I'm that error.

`<time am-time-ago="post.uploadedAt"></time>`

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"post.uploadedAt","newVal":"2015-07-29T01:14:19.873Z","oldVal":"2015-07-29T01:14:19.873Z"},{"msg":"post.uploadedAt","newVal":"2015-07-29T01:11:57.581Z","oldVal":"2015-07-29T01:11:57.581Z"}],[{"msg":"post.uploadedAt","newVal":"2015-07-29T01:14:19.873Z","oldVal":"2015-07-29T01:14:19.873Z"},{"msg":"post.uploadedAt","newVal":"2015-07-29T01:11:57.581Z","oldVal":"2015-07-29T01:11:57.581Z"}],[{"msg":"post.uploadedAt","newVal":"2015-07-29T01:14:19.873Z","oldVal":"2015-07-29T01:14:19.873Z"},{"msg":"post.uploadedAt","newVal":"2015-07-29T01:11:57.581Z","oldVal":"2015-07-29T01:11:57.581Z"}],[{"msg":"post.uploadedAt","newVal":"2015-07-29T01:14:19.873Z","oldVal":"2015-07-29T01:14:19.873Z"},{"msg":"post.uploadedAt","newVal":"2015-07-29T01:11:57.581Z","oldVal":"2015-07-29T01:11:57.581Z"}],[{"msg":"post.uploadedAt","newVal":"2015-07-29T01:14:19.873Z","oldVal":"2015-07-29T01:14:19.873Z"},{"msg":"post.uploadedAt","newVal":"2015-07-29T01:11:57.581Z","oldVal":"2015-07-29T01:11:57.581Z"}]]
```

Anyone knows how to solve?

Comment: There is a watch on `post.uploadedAt` which is getting fired continuously because something in the watch handler is changing what is being watched. This causes infinite loop.

Comment: I think it's why `post` is a resulto of a Meteor publish/subscribe. Is there a way to stop watch `post.uploadedAt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved that removing the `am-time-ago` directive and using `moment().fromNow()` at controller like this:

View:

```
<time ng-bind="timeAgo(post.uploadedAt)"></time>
```

Controller

```
$scope.timeAgo = function (time) {
    return moment(time).fromNow();
};
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Diego. Sorted it for me too.. Presumably it's about how am-time-ago dynamically "watches" the variable or something. Still learning Angular so I may be wrong here..